# Tracing Javascript warning from library

Tags: javascript

I have a script that uses Raphaël, a Javascript library to work with SVGs. In my code I am doing something wrong because of that I am getting a warning from the library.

That warning comes from some line in the library. It would be great to trace the stack from when that warning occur to know where in my code is the line that causes the warning.

Using console.trace doesn't help, so I ask, is there a way to trace a warning that comes from a Javascript Library?

(PS: I looked into modifying the library to print stack traces, but that is just too hard.)

Edit:

The warning itself is:

"Unexpected value NaN parsing width attribute."

I would like to trace the error to know where in my code am I sending a NaN to a Raphael function.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, your warnings are probably something like "Invalid syntax M,0,0" when you're trying to create paths (more details would be welcome) ?

If it is, then you can't have a stack trace because it's an SVG error (the SVG engine is telling that a DOM SVG element is erroneous, but it won't tell you when this node has been created).

Check the input that you're feeding into the elements that you are creating with Raphael.

Comment: It seems to be a SVG error. You can try to see what is the erroneous element (use the DOM tree viewer), then deduce what is the Raphael.js API call which could create it. I think that 'width' is used for the canvas and rect elements, maybe you should start by this.